# Swift + Firebase: randomly picking a group of objects using a query to the server

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am building a quiz app for iOS using Swift and using Firebase as a backend. I want to be able to make a query that picks 10 random questions and returns them.

[image]

Comment: Firebase doesn't have a server-side `random()` operation, so that won't be possible. There was a decent discussion about this a while back on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/C-mILPmGpbI/0kTAopALiXsJ

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the problem with what that post sujests is that I plan to have a lot of questions, and the time it takes to retrieve the questions and then pick some randomly will only get longer as there are more questions.

Comment: Instead of one time getting 10 questions you could do ten times getting 1 question.

Comment: @AndréKool I need to randomly pick the questions though

Comment: I'll post an answer in 10 min or so, i'm not so good in swift

Comment: Go check out my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038712/how-do-i-retrieve-a-random-object-from-firebase-using-a-sequential-id/53330758#53330758). If all you need is 10 questions then I don't think it would be too overbearing to run 10 consecutive random queries that are formatted like the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all for my answer you need to give each question a value like this:

```
    {
      "question1": {
        "question" : "Do you know swift",
        "answer" : "Nope",
        "value": 1
      },
      "question2": {
        "question" : "Do you know firebase",
        "answer" : "A bit",
        "value" : 2
      }
    }
```

After that it's recommended to add an index in your firebase rules ([firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html)) like this:

```
    {
      "rules": {
        "questions": {
          ".indexOn": ["value"]
        }
      }
    }
```

Next up is the swift part:

```
//Use a for loop to get 10 questions
for _ in 1...10{
  //generate a random number between 1 and the amount of questions you have
  var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(amountOfQuestions - 1)) + 1

  //The reference to your questions in firebase (this is an example from firebase itself)
  let ref = Firebase(url: "https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs")
    //Order the questions on their value and get the one that has the random value
  ref.queryOrderedByChild("value").queryEqualToValue(randomNumber)
    .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
      snapshot in
        //Do something with the question
        println(snapshot.key)
    })
}
```

The actual swift code may be flawed and for the firebase specific code take a look at [Ios documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)

Comment: @AndréKoolI just checked this, I have 2 errors. I will add a screenshot of the errors to my original post.

Comment: I updated the for loop in my answer to hopefully correct swift code, this should solve the first error, The second error is caused because you added an extra bracket at the end so just remove that. Remember that i wrote sample code, simply copy and past it will give you some errors. You will atleast have to change the reference to firebase to match your own frebase.

Comment: Thats not a great option because you will be making alot of calls to the server