# How to get a number of random items from the Firebase Realtime Database using server-side queries?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, server

I am writing an Android app that retrieves its data (in this case Questions) from Firebase' Real-Time database.

When the app starts I want to retrieve X random questions from the DB. However I do not want to fetch all of the questions and take random ones in the client side.

I know that I can limit the number of entries to fetch but they wont be random.
I tried to see if I can write a server side to get the random data but I don't see how I can do it. I would write a PHP script in the server but It seems that there are only Cloud Functions.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I have a few ideas, most of which do involve cloud functions.  However, before I start looking into an approach, I need a few more details.  First, have you deployed cloud functions before?  If not, you should perform some tutorials or watch the [Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/user/Firebase/playlists) cloud function videos on youtube.  Second, I need to know more about the randomness.  Do you want truly random, or do you want a random shuffle (see everything once, but in random order)?

Comment: Dan McGrath wrote a great answer a while ago on how to select a random document from Cloud Firestore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection. While Realtime Database uses a different data model, the same approach could work there.

Comment: And for a slightly different version from what Frank linked you can take a look at [my answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35524816/4916627) that is about getting random items from the realtime database.